# Display information about linked models fields in the django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

These are my models:

```
class Partner(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Organisation name")

class ResearchActivity(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    partner = models.ManyToManyField(ActivityPartner, blank=True)
```

I'd like, in the Django administration forms, to have a field in my `Partner` edit form representing the `ResearchActivity` linked to that Partner.

Can this be achieved by adding a field to my Partner model (say, naming it `linked_partner`) and then edit my admin.py like so:

```
@admin.register(ActivityPartner)
class ActivityPartnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['academic',]
    autocomplete_fields = ['partnership_type', 'relationship_type', 'academic_links']

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {'live_contract': ResearchActivity.objects.all().filter(linked_partner__id=request.ResearchActivity.partner.id)}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just come across in the [`display() decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator), new from Django 3.2. With it, I can simply do:

```
@admin.register(ActivityPartner)
class ActivityPartnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['academic',]
    autocomplete_fields = ['partnership_type', 'relationship_type', 'academic_links',]

    readonly_fields = ('get_ra',)

    @admin.display(description='Live contract(s)')
    def get_ra(self, obj):
        return list(ResearchActivity.objects.filter(partner=obj.id))
```

to achieve what I want.

If I also wanted to edit those ManyToMany relations, I can use the [`inlines` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models):

```
class LiveContractsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ResearchActivity.partner.through

@admin.register(ActivityPartner)
class ActivityPartnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [
        LiveContractsInline,
    ]
```